# EF - Doing 'Include' on navigation properties when data is retrieved through a SP

Tags: entity-framework, include, navigation-properties

When using LINQ to retrieve data we can also get its navigation properties with an include as follows:

```
IQueryable<Location> locations = from c in ClientContext.Locations.Include("LocationType") select c;
        return locations;
```

How can we do the same, when we call a SP through the EF? I have a function import which returns the same object as the above query does:

```
return (IQueryable<Location>)ClientContext.GetLocationsPerUser(userId, getSubLocations);
```

How can I attach the LocationType entity to the above set? Is it possible or will I have to expose it from the SP itself?

Comment: Well, not really - either your stored procedure already "includes" those extra entities in its `SELECT` statement, or then you have to extend it to support that. The `Include` works as long as EF can generate the SQL statement itself - but if you stop EF from doing so, by using a stored procedure, then it's **your job** to include all those extra entities you might need

Comment: by including extra entities you mean returning a composition of fields from both entities right? I can't retrieve a Location entity with an associated locationtype entity?

Comment: Yes, that's what `Include` basically does - it joins an extra table and fetches all defined columns for it. If you let EF do its work itself, it can do that "dynamically" on a per-request basis - if you want to handle this in your stored procedure, you're on your own and have to provide some way to do this